# nvme command is unusable with error: bash: nvme: command not found

Tags: bash, nvme

Drivers are loaded but I can't use the command:

```
lsmod | grep nvme
nvme                   32375  0 
nvme_core              58654  1 nvme
```

Error:

> bash: nvme: command not found...

Comment: If something is in the list of lsmod this does not mean that the command line utility with the same name is also available to you. Have you actually installed this? https://github.com/linux-nvme/nvme-cli

Comment: thanks that worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install it.  On RHEL/Fedora systems:

```
sudo dnf install nvme-cli
```

Someone else can tell you how to do it for Ubuntu.  (Sorry, I'm a Red Hat guy.)

Answer (score 2):

on Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install nvme-cli
```